# How can I use a postgres variable in my SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I'm storing a value in a variable `featureId` and then trying to use that value in my SELECT statement, but postgres seems to be taking the name literally and looking for a column called "featureid". I'm getting an error "ERROR:  column "featureid" does not exist
LINE 4: featureId,"

My code is below. How can I use the value of the variable in my SELECT statement?

```
SELECT id INTO featureId FROM tableA WHERE NAME = 'some value';

INSERT INTO tableB (client_id, feature_id, does_have)
  SELECT
  id,
  featureId,
  TRUE
FROM tableA
```

Comment: Where is the declaration and the rest of the block?

Comment: @stickybit there isn't one. I'm just running this piece by piece in the editor at the moment

Comment: are you tryng to write a trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a declared variable your `SELECT INTO` is the version of [`SELECT INTO` that creates a table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html). To see it for yourself try:

```
SELECT id
       INTO featureid
       FROM tablea
       WHERE name = 'some value';

SELECT *
       FROM featureid;
```

For assigning the value to a variable the variable must be declared. You can use an anonymous `DO` block.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  featureid tablea.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT id
         INTO featureid
         FROM tablea
         WHERE name = 'some value';

  INSERT INTO tableb
              (client_id,
               feature_id,
               does_have)
              SELECT id,
                     featureid,
                     true
                     FROM tablea;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are few errors on what you're tryng to do:

- sql is **declarative** language so you're asking what to do not how to do and this is for this reason that you cannot store variables and some statements like declare and begin-end should be used in trigger and not in a simple query.
- you are executing two statements: **select** and **insert into** and they are executed one after the other, so once again you cannot store a variable.
- insert into, insert a single record but potentially you're tryng to retrieve more data with your select statement (if NAME is not unique)

if 'some-value' is a known constant and NAME is unique just insert that value in the where clause of the insert into. If you're tryng to insert more data take a look on **bulk insert** syntax of postgres: [bulk insert](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTik-czdrdLmbcG966HoF72F2b561R9Uuh54Os94f@mail.gmail.com)